# Properly access ChangeNotifierProvider from Consumer Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I can't access my `ChangeNotifierProvider<QuestionProvider>` from `Consumer<QuestionProvider>` but I don't understand why, it's defined deeper in the widget tree compared to its provider.

I defined my provider here :

```
body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<QuestionProvider>(
            //TODO : question provider arguments should come from internet
            create: (newContext) => QuestionProvider([], pageController),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TypeAndSettingsRow(),
```

Consumer is defined in a next widget defined inside `TypeAndSettingsRow` :

```
class TypeAndSettingsRow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TypeAndSettingsRow> createState() => _TypeAndSettingsRowState();
}

class _TypeAndSettingsRowState extends State<TypeAndSettingsRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void showPopoverType() {
      int thisIsTrue = 0;
      double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9;
      showPopover(
        context: context,
        tion(milliseconds: 150),
        bodyBuilder: (context) => CheckboxListTileRow(),
```

And finally `CheckboxListTileRow` :

```
class _CheckboxListTileRowState extends State<CheckboxListTileRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<QuestionProvider>(builder: ((context, value, child) {
```

`QuestionProvider` :

```
class QuestionProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
```

When I open `CheckboxListTileRow` this is the error :

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<QuestionProvider> above this Consumer<QuestionProvider> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
 You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer<QuestionProvider> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<QuestionProvider>.
```

I don't understand which is the problem because my provider is defined above in the widget tree respect of its consumer so it should be reachable.

Maybe there are some errors with `context`s?

**EDIT** :

Found out that the problem is `showPopover` form  [popover package](https://pub.dev/packages/popover), when I try to access `ChangeNotifierProvider` with `Consumer` within `showPopover`  this error is thrown but if I do it outside then it works.
Probably it creates a new route and I can't access my provider anymore.
Hope this new hint can help to fix because question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Make sure that Consumer<QuestionProvider> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<QuestionProvider>.
```

This means you have not mentioned the provider class in your `main.dart` file.
For that, you have to use the following code.

```
Provider(
  create: (_) => QuestionProvider(),
  child: MyApp(),
),
```

If you have multiple providers you can use the following code.

```
MultiProvider(
 providers: [
      QuestionProvider(),
      .....
     ]

  )
```

Comment: But I don't want to put this provider so high in the widget tree, I want to put it in the class where I defined it

Comment: Question edited, try to take a look now please

Comment: You are using `consumer` in another class and the `ChangeNotifierProvider` inside `GestureDetector` that's why the `consumer` can not able to find the `Provider<QuestionProvider>`

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I don't understand which is the problem

Answer (score 0):

why did you use
**changeNotifierProvider** on root of your widget tree? if you haven't need to like that you can use it where ever in your widget tree and use **consumer as it's on child** not another widget

Comment: In fact I didn't placed on the top of my widget tree and don't know why he did it